# How would I setup the autotile bitmask for this tile set?

Tags: godot-3, tile-bitmasking

I'm using Godot. I've figured out how to do the main tiles like you see in the following image, but I have no clue where to go from here. The tile set is from PixiVan located here [PixiVan Forest Tile Set](https://pixivan.itch.io/top-down-forest-tileset)[image: Tile set bitmask]

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Does this have to be for Godot 3, or are you able to also do this in Godot 4?